# MarshallByRefObject

Tags: .net-remoting

Just a quick one for an expert in the field :)

Can I use the marshallbyrefobject class to get objects to be reference across a network, rather than just across application domains?

If not, is there another set of classes to do this? i.e. reference and use an object across a network where that object is processed and stored at the remote location.

Thanks a million,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `MarshalByRefObject` is the base class for remotely accessible objects in [.NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.71).aspx). It works whether the remote object is in another application domain in the same process or on an application domain on the other side of the globe.

By the way, .NET Remoting is considered obsolete in favor of newer technologies like [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx). While it's still suitable for some applications, most new applications should consider using WCF.